# Is the Mono Developer Support from Novell worth it?

Tags: mono

My company are thinking about using Mono for an upcoming product, so we were thinking about the $12,995 [Mono Kickstart](http://www.mono-project.com/Kickstart) support from Novell.

Anybody here used it, is it worth it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i were you i'd probably start the project and then only if i needed support for mono buy the product.  that way if you dont need it you wont be wasting the $13k.